# A question about Gaussian primes generated by the function $w(z)=z^2+i$

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, gaussian-integers

While reading [this paper](https://faculty.washington.edu/etou/documents/FuentesMeiroseTou-PGP_Preprint.pdf) and after some experiments, I asked myself the following question.

Given

- the Gaussian integer $z_0=a+bi$, with $a\gt b$ and $b$ not divisible by $3$
- its conjugate $\bar{z_0}=a-bi$
- the function $w(z)=z^2+i$,

prove or disprove that **if both $w(z_0)$ and $w(\bar{z_0})$ are Gaussian primes then, necessarily, $3|a$.**

In other words, both
$$(a^2+b^2)^2+4ab+1$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^2-4ab+1$$
have to be ordinary primes congruent to $1\;mod\;4$.

Some examples:
$$z_0=3+i$$
$$z_0=6+4i$$
$$z_0=9+i$$
$$z_0=12+4i$$
$$z_0=15+5i$$

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $3 \nmid a$.  Then both $a$ and $b$ are $\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$, so

$$(a^2+b^2)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3, \\
4ab \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3.$$

There is some choice of sign in front of $4ab$ which makes that term $1 \pmod 3$, which makes $(a^2+b^2)^2 \pm 4ab + 1 \equiv 1 + 1 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  It is impossible for this to be a prime congruent to $1$ mod $4$.  This contradiction forces $3 \mid a$ as conjectured.